# Power Editor upload not including valid user IDs in custom audience

Tags: upload

uploaded CSV file with 4000 Facebook valid user id, uploaded completed with no errors from power editor, but only 20 of the user id were uploaded into the custom audience. Repeated with txt file one user id per line with the same result only 20 user Id in custom audience.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Got the same problem…